# window.open doesn't work in http post angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, window.open

Here's my code:

```
        $rootScope.http({
            url: myUrl,
            method: "POST",
            data: "",
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data.uri); //for test, and I see correct uri shows up here.
            window.open(data.uri, ''); return false; //window doesn't open.
        });
```

The window.open doesn't work inside the `.success`, but it does work outside the http post method. Something is wrong when comes to callback function. I met very same issue in `$.ajax` and fixed it. But same solution doesn't work here for angular.

Comment: Are there errors in the console? Also, do you happen to have a pop-up blocker enabled? I also have a feeling `window` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: And $window.open() doesn't work?

Comment: I'm doing this development for mobile, so I can't see the pop-up blocker. I have a not so good fix, is that, I do `var win = window.open()` before the callback, then inside `.success`, I change the window's location by `win.location = ...`. But it doesn't give nice visual result. I mean user will see a blank page for one second, then jump to the actual url, which is not cool.

Comment: The fix I mentioned above works okay in chrome browser, but more slower in safari, I wonder is there a better way to fix this issue. If not, I'll just use current fix.

Comment: This works fine for me in Chrome. Curious, does it work if you try just `window.open()` or `window.open(data.uri)`?

Comment: it does work without http post request. It's just inside won't work.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the similar problem before and the reason is simple; in the most of the modern browsers, browsers will not allow the `window.open()` call which are not the direct result of user activity.

Here, your `window.open()` is being triggered in an asynchronous call which is not being called by a user action, for example: clicking on a link or a button.

You can fix this problem by disabling the popup blocker but we have to notify the user that their popup blocker is enabled. For that, you can do something like this:

```
    $rootScope.http({
        url: myUrl,
        method: "POST",
        data: "",
    }).success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.popupWindow = window.open(data.uri, '');

        $timeout(function() {                                                                                       
             // Check if popup blocker is enabled by verifying the height of the new poup                                                                     
             if (!$rootScope.popupWindow || $rootScope.popupWindow.outerHeight === 0) {
                 alert("Please disable the popup blocker");
             }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

(*Note:* I've tested this is a browser, not sure in the mobile but this should work)

Comment: But how to disable the popup blocker on the phone? I'm afraid most users won't know how to do it too... I tested chrome on iphone and it seems doesn't have an option for enable/disable popup at all.

Comment: don't use pop-ups